# Looping row by row and computing days and amounts- SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help with the following:

In the following table (sample), the Dayscount field hould have the difference between the Txndate in the current row and the Txndate in the next row provided the Acctno in both rows are the same. If the AcctNo is different, then the Dayscount should be derived from a given fixed date -(31 Mar 12 has been used in the example). The Product column will have the product of the Amount1 and DaysCount

```
+--------+------------------+----------------------+---------+-------------+----------+
|  P_ID  |      AcctNo      |              TxnDate | Amount1 |   DAYSCOUNT |  Product |
+--------+------------------+----------------------+---------+-------------+----------+
| 108161 | 0019061_A0100501 | 30/01/2012           |     250 |             |          |
| 108162 | 0019061_A0100501 | 03/02/2012           |  -23000 |             |          |
| 108163 | 0019061_A0100502 | 09/02/2012           |    -215 |             |          |
| 108164 | 0019061_A0100502 | 24/02/2012           |   -1103 |             |          |
+--------+------------------+----------------------+---------+-------------+----------+
```

The expected output is shown below:

```
+--------+------------------+--------------------------+----------+-----------+---------------+
|  P_ID  |      AcctNo      |              TxnDate     | Amount1  | DAYSCOUNT |    Product    |
+--------+------------------+--------------------------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 108161 | 0019061_A0100501 | 30/01/2012               |      250 |         4 |          1000 |
| 108162 | 0019061_A0100501 | 03/02/2012               |   -23000 |        57 |      -1311000 |
| 108163 | 0019061_A0100502 | 09/02/2012               |     -215 |        15 |         -3225 |
| 108164 | 0019061_A0100502 | 24/02/2012               |    -1103 |        36 |        -39708 |
|        |                  |                          |          |           |               |
+--------+------------------+--------------------------+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use option with [OUTER APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator.

Right table expression is processed every time for each row from the left table expression.The final result-set contains all the selected columns from the left table expression followed by all the columns of right table expression. OUTER APLLY for those rows for which there are no corresponding matches in right table expression, it contains NULL values in columns of right table expression.

```
SELECT t.P_ID, t.AcctNo, t.TxnDate, Amount1, 
       DATEDIFF(day, t.TxnDate, CASE WHEN t.AcctNo = o.AcctNo THEN o.TxnDate ELSE '20120331' END) AS DAYSCOUNT,
       DATEDIFF(day, t.TxnDate, CASE WHEN t.AcctNo = o.AcctNo THEN o.TxnDate ELSE '20120331' END) * Amount1 AS Product
FROM dbo.test76 t OUTER APPLY (
                               SELECT TOP 1 t2.TxnDate, t2.AcctNo
                               FROM dbo.test76 t2
                               WHERE t.P_ID < t2.P_ID
                               ORDER BY P_ID ASC
                               ) o
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80b36/3)

For improving performance use this index

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.test76(P_ID) INCLUDE(AcctNo, TxnDate, Amount1)
```

Comment: This is giving the desired result, but taking too long to execute. After 45 minutes, it had completed 11000 rows out of the total 300000+ rows

Comment: Thanks. The indexing gives the results very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to loop the table again and again consider using recursive with class

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY P_ID) AS RowNumber, *
    FROM TableName)

SELECT CTE1.P_ID,
       CTE1.AcctNo,
       CTE1.TxnDate,
       CTE1.Amount1, 
       DATEDIFF (DD, 
          CTE1.TxnDate,
          CASE WHEN CTE1.AcctNo = ISNULL(CTE2.AcctNo,'')
               THEN CTE2.TxnDate
               ELSE '20120331'
          END) AS DAYSCOUNT,
       DATEDIFF (DD,
          CTE1.TxnDate,
          CASE WHEN CTE1.AcctNo = ISNULL(CTE2.AcctNo,'')
               THEN CTE2.TxnDate
               ELSE '20120331'
          END) * CTE1.Amount1 AS Product
       FROM CTE AS CTE1
LEFT JOIN CTE AS CTE2 ON (CTE1.RowNumber + 1 = CTE2.RowNumber)
```

Comment: The DaysCount are calculated correctly and fast. However, the CTE1.Product returns NULL for all rows whereas it should contain the product of the DAYSCOUNT and Amount1.

Comment: I tried changing the second last line as   "CTE1.Amount1 * CTE1.Dayscount as Product" but it returns NULL for all rows.

Comment: I should have read the question properly. I've updated my answer to include the Product calculation. Looks like your happy with with Alexander's answer anyway.

Comment: This worked after making a small change. ie. after adding "CTE1.TxnDate" as the second argument in the second Datediff in the code. Thanks.